# Why my internal hard disk can be ejected?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, removable-media

I have 6 hard disks in my computer and one DVD.
The disk that I connect to the 6th SATA port is a regular disk. But my Windows 7 64 bit shows it as a removable drive. I can eject my hard disk! Just like a pen drive.
If I connect another disk to the 6th port, I can eject that disk too. So it has nothing to do with the physical disk, it must be something related to Windows or BIOS

I don't understand why Windows 7 is seeing a normal hard disk as removable.
In Computer Management - Disk Management, the disk looks identical to the others - there is nothing there to suggest the drive is different from the others.
But in the tray I have the icon to eject it.

The motherboard model is ASUS F2A85 V PRO FM2 and it has 7 SATA ports. All the disks are formatted normally, no Dynamic Disk, no RAID, nothing special.

How can I tell Windows 7 to treat the disk exactly like the others, so it can't be ejected?

Comment: in bios does the sata is properly listed?

Comment: That's probably your one and only eSATA port. Check if it's red port on your MB. [eSATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA)

Comment: The disk is properly listed in BIOS. The 5th disk is identical also - ST3000DM001. I can see no difference between 5th and 6th in BIOS.

Comment: The disk is not connected on the eSATA port. The eSATA port is on the rear of the motherboard (where the VGA, HDMI, audio and USB ports are)

Answer (score 2):

Its Normal for AHCI SATA mode which supports a feature called hot swapping : Enables you to swap hard disk without powering down the whole system

Citation : [Internal SATA hard disk shows up as removable device on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/92264/internal-sata-hard-disk-shows-up-as-removable-device-on-windows-7)

You are supposed to update Your SATA driver : Microsoft provide AHCI driver than install this hotfix

MS KB article : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977178

INTEL than install [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software%20Products&ProductLine=Chipset%20Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Rapid%20Storage%20Technology) driver

Comment: I have installed the last chipsed driver from the motherboard manufacturer (ASUS) and still I can eject my disk