# BitLocker refuses to enable via RDP on data drive but Ok on the OS drive

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I've recently installed Windows 10 Enterprise on an old AMD-based machine without a TPM.  I use it mostly via Remote Desktop, due to lack of monitors and keyboards.

While connected via RDP, I then:

- enabled the local policy that allows BitLocker without a TPM.
- attempted then to switch on BitLocker on the D drive, which is <strike>a separate physical 3TB drive freshly formatted as 2TB</strike> a separate NTFS partition on the OS HDD.

**Edit: my apologies.  The D: drive isn't a separate physical drive, it's a separate NTFS partition on the same physical drive as the OS.**

All I got was an error message saying Access is Denied:

[image: Access is denied message]

Didn't have much luck Googling, but discovered that if I connected directly to the computer (ie not RDP, but separate monitor, keyboard and mouse), BitLocker would enable straightaway, prompting for a password and recovery file location as you'd expect.

**Edit: The behaviour on the E: Drive (which is the separate physical 3TB drive freshly formatted as 2TB), is the same.  BitLocker enables when connected directly, but not over RDP.**

Once reconnected to the computer via RDP, I found that it would let me manage BitLocker on the D Drive (or the E: Drive), including switching it off and changing the password.

It would also let me switch BitLocker on, on the C Drive - the OS drive, all via RDP.

This wasn't just a glitch - I was able to switch off BitLocker, thus decrypting the drive (which was empty), and then get the Access is Denied message again as before.

Again, once enabled via a direct connection, all was well over RDP again.

Why would it be different on the two discs?

**Edit: I don't think any of the drives are being recognised as removable media:**

[image]

Although weirdly, they both appear as portable further down the Device Manager list.

Comment: How is that that D: drive connected to the host computer?

Comment: Yes, C: and D:, both SATA drives installed in the Win 10 machine.  Connected via RDP from a Win 7 PC.

Comment: Is D being [recognized as "removable media"](http://superuser.com/questions/92264/internal-sata-hard-disk-shows-up-as-removable-device-on-windows-7) by any chance?

Comment: Don't think so - see my edit.

Comment: See also my corrections.  Apologies for the mixup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try enabling this group policy (using run / windowskey+r, "gpedit.msc"):

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access > All Removable Storage > Allow direct access in remote sessions

(described here:
http://www.yellow-bricks.com/2010/11/06/access-denied-when-encrypting-a-memory-stick-with-bitlocker/
)

It may be that "removable drive" for bitlocker purposes is slightly different from "removable drive" for "how stuff looks in device manager" purposes, and enabling that policy may help. Also try a USB stick (or some other genuinely removable drive) after enabling that policy, and see whether you can use bitlocker on that.

Comment: Very odd! The same procedure (Bitlocker over RDP) works fine on W2012 R2, but I get this behaviour on W10.

Comment: This just worked on Windows 11. Oddly enough, the other Win11 I was setting up worked no problem. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -2):

rdp protocol treats external usb drives as mapped network drives and not as external usb devices which bitlocker handles. There is no resolution to this

Comment: "There is no resolution to this" The accepted answer suggests otherwise ...